# Port number 8443 is shown in the browser address bar when using Tomcat with HTTPS

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I am working on a Spring MVC application and I have deployed that on a Tomcat installation on the server. In the configuration which I will post below of Tomcat and Spring, HTTP communication occurs on port 80 and HTTPS on port 8443.

Now when the application is deployed, I can see in the browser URL as

> https://domainname.com:8443/nameOfPage

I don't want want to show the *port number* to the user. What should I do, kindly let me know.

Thank you.

---

*Spring Security* config.xml

```
<security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <security:form-login login-page="/"
                         default-target-url="/canvas/list"
                         always-use-default-target="false"
                         authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />

    <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me"
                          user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                          token-validity-seconds="1209600"
                          data-source-ref="dataSource" />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/"
                     delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                     invalidate-session="true"
                     logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/canvas/list" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
    </security:port-mappings>

</security>
```

Apache Tomcat *server.xml*:

```
<Connector port="80"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to use port 443 instead.

The browser will always tell you if you're using a non-standard port, and the standard port for HTTPS is 443.

Similarly, for HTTP if you use any port other than 80, the port number will show in the address bar.

Comment: Hello, I changed the port number as you said, now I don't see the port number, but after login I see blank page. I am updating my post to add the intercept-url where it is showing me blank page, kindly check it.

Comment: @Akshay That's a different question and you should probably post it separately to get more attention. The answer to the original question is that the browser will always show a non-standard port. (I'm presuming you changed both `redirectPort` and `port` in server.xml)

Comment: Yes. I did change both ports. There is a AJP 1.3 connector port listening on 8009 and redirecting to 8443, should I change that too?

Comment: Well yes, but unless you have Apache in front of tomcat it won't be the issue here. Seriously though - you should post a new question - comments are not the correct place for this, and your edit above makes the question read strangely because it's a mix of the original 8443 vs 443 question and the new issue.

Comment: Hello, I have posted my question, can you have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482362/spring-security-https-pages-are-blank-after-login

Comment: I'll try, but nothing is jumping out at me immediately and the day job is calling :)